# Training convolutional neural network (CNN) with images captured using Xbox Kinect in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

Can i train a convolutional neural network (CNN) on images captured with Xbox Kinect Sensor in Keras.?

Will using depth images rather than the ordinary RGB image increase the accuracy of the model that I intend to use to classify hand gestures.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can train CNNs with any signal...

In addition to an RGB image both Kinect versions, although working on different principles, yield a depth image. That means instead of intensity information each pixel encodes the distance from the object to the camera.

Processing intensity and depth images is pretty much the same thing. You can apply the same techniques to both.